# Vertical Blue, Green, or Gray lines in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am seeing these vertical blue and green lines on the right border of the Android Studio:

[image]

What do these lines mean? Is there a way to remove them as they are a little annoying. I don't remember seeing them in previous versions of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's look like git is initialize/contain in your project.
If you update git initialize code then you can see those different blue/green color as per add/update/deletion of code.

delete '.git' folder from your project root directory and restart your android studio.

**Note:** '.git' folder is hidden folder.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way to remove them?

Comment: delete '.git' folder from your project root directory and restart your android studio.

Note: '.git' folder is hidden folder.

Comment: Thanks, it did work I didn't even need to restart Android Studio. Is there a way to disable this without removing .git folder? Does Android Studio have any option?

Comment: sorry, i dont know about that

Answer (score 3):

The tool is showing you lines which have changed as far as VCS (rev control, in your case git) is concerned.  This gives you a quick look at what has changed within the file compared to the last commit on your current branch.

There is no way to disable this in the UI AFAIK.  You may try looking in Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts to see if you can find a setting to disable this.

Comment: Thanks. You are right it looks like under Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts  under VCS there are some options.